# SQL Counting different email domains

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to count the number of email addresses of different email domains.

```
name     | email
---------+----------------------
Jack     | jack@email.com
John     | john@something.com
Mike     | mike@email.com
```

The result should look like

```
domain        | count
--------------+-----------------
email.com     | 2
something.com | 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please show us the code that you've tried to far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MySQL**, you can use following query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) AS 'domain',
       COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM table1
GROUP BY domain;
```

**Output**

```
|     domain    | count |
|---------------|-------|
|     email.com |     2 |
| something.com |     1 |
```

Test this query here
[MySQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24b2b5/4)

Comment: Can you reference a expression by it's alias in `GROUP BY` in MySQL? :o

Answer (score 0):

In sql server, you can use this : [SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f46059/1)

```
select email, count(*) from (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) + 1, 255) email from yourtable
) as T group by email
```

You can try this in MySQL : [SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96a58e/2)

```
select email, count(*) from (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(email, locate('@', email) + 1, 255) email from Table1
) as T group by email
```